# Acesso a propriedades de objetos em uma lista (KOTLIN). Por quê é tão complicado?

Tags: kotlin

Eu estou tentando fazer uma coisa que eu julgo extremamente simples: Dada uma classe chamada `Student`, eu instanciei 3 estudantes e adicionei em uma lista (`mutableListOf`). Feito isso, eu quero acessar o nome dos estudantes da lista.

Parece simples, não é? Se eu fosse implementar uma linguagem de programação eu faria assim:

```
lista.get(1).name
```

Mas em Kotlin não é assim, e pior, eu ainda não descobri como faz!

Segue abaixo um código exemplo:

```
class Student(
    name : String,
    age : Int,
    course : String,
)

fun main() {

    var s1 = Student("Ana", 25, "Eng")
    var s2 = Student("Joao", 30, "Geo")
    var s3 = Student("Flavio", 17, "Publicidade") 
    var s4 = Student("Bruno", 33, "Adm")     

    var test = mutableListOf(s1,s2,s3)
    test.add(s4)

    println(test.get(1))
}
```

Comment: Experimenta adicionar `val` ou `var` antes do nome das variáveis no construtor. https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html#constructors

Answer (score 11):

Da forma que você declarou a classe `Student`, as variáveis `name`, `age` e `course`  são apenas parâmetros passados ao construtor. Se você quer que eles se tornem propriedades da classe, você deve adicionar a *keyword* `val` ou `var` antes do nome da variável:

```
class Student(
    val name : String,
    val age : Int,
    val course : String
)
```

Você pode ler mais sobre a sintaxe do construtor [na documentação](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html#constructors).

---

Uma dica: graças ao *[operator overloading](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/operator-overloading.html#indexed)*, é possível acessar elementos de uma lista com uma notação similar a de arrays:

```
println(test[1].name)
```

Comment: Perfeito! Muito obrigado, deu certo